# Octave GUI crashing on Windows 10

Tags: user-interface, command-line, command-line-interface, octave, gnu

I was working on Octave GUI for a while now on my Windows 10 PC. The last time I did run it, I just docked out the command window from the GUI main frame, and after my work I closed the app. After that whenever I tried to open the Octave GUI app, it somewhat launched with two windows (mainframe and command window separately) and while loading, it got crashed and automatically closed. This problem is only occurring with the GUI app while the CLI is working perfectly. I tried uninstalling the app and then re-installing but the problem was persistent!!!

Can someone tell me what is the problem arising here and how should I solve it?

Comment: Bugreport on Savannah: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?54813

Comment: any updates on this bug? i am running octave 7.2.0 on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me also. Try installing Octave using installer 
found in this [link](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.4.1-w64-installer.exe) (64bit) or [link](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.4.1-w32-installer.exe) (32bit).

After installing run the Octave GUI. It will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the application cannot be opened in high resolution. Mine happened when I accidentally maximized the window in my recommended screen resolution (1920x1080).

**Try reducing the screen resolution (Display settings -> resolution). Then open the GNUOctave(GUI) and reduce its window size. Then you can increase the resolution back to original and do not increase the size of the Octave window again. It would work fine**